# mysql error handling in function

Tags: mysql

I am trying to do error handling as I can do in stored procedures in mysql but functions don't support to support them. Is there a way I can do something like this?

```
delimiter //

CREATE FUNCTION supports_ft()
    RETURNS INT
    BEGIN
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE 'HY000' return 0;
    SELECT @@innodb_ft_cache_size;
    return 1;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

Functions support exception handlers, but that won't necessarily catch a blatantly invalid operation that could never succeed, such as what you are trying here, which is an unbounded select.  This is only supported in stored procedures, not functions (or triggers).

```
ERROR 1415 (0A000): Not allowed to return a result set from a function
```

You need to try to load the system variable's content into a dummy variable.  The following should work, unless MySQL tries to validate the variable at function declaration time, which it may or may not... you'll need to verify:

```
SET @dummy = @@innodb_ft_cache_size;
```

If validation is done early, you'll need to use a prepared statement to avoid that early validation.

`HY000` is a pretty vague sqlstate, and you might be better off with `DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION`.